# I am facing an issue to execute AWS Lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[image]

While deploying lambda in C# I am getting an error as - "errorType": "LambdaException",   "errorMessage": "Could not find the specified handler assembly with the file name '/var/task/AWSLambda1.dll' or '/var/task/AWSLambda1.ni.dll'. The assembly should be located in the root of your uploaded .zip file.".
as  a beginner Could any one provide me the steps to execute lambda in C#?

Comment: I usually use the built-in publish option within C# (install the [toolkit](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/)), but you can also deploy by zip. Is your .dll file in a folder in your .zip file or is it in the root?

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but let me put my solution here to save someone else's time.
I also got this type of error and fixed the error by matching the AWS Lambda function handler name the same as the assembly name of the handler function in the code/zip file.
AWS Lambda Handler can be found under the Runtime settings of the Code tab.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that your runtime settings are not set to execute your function. Perform the following steps to modify your setting:

1. Navigate to your AWS Lambda function.
2. Under your Lambda, scroll down and navigate to Code tab.
3. Scroll down to Runtime settings:

[image]

Modify the name to your function handler:
[image]

This worked with me.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you most likely created the lambda locally first and then tried to upload the code using dotnet cli or VS.

Try before deploying to go to your `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` file in the solution and change `function-handler` value to the value that corresponds to the real namespace of your application that processes the event -`{namespace of your application}::{function name}`, for example `AWSLambda1::AWSLambda1.Function::FunctionHandler` or just change it in your publish form if you are deploying using VS:

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely the answer to successfully Publish to AWS Lambda right-clicking from Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.  In fact, the quoted example in the text of this answer "AWSLambda1::AWSLambda1.Function::FunctionHandler" was EXACTLY character-for-character what I needed doing this the first time from the AWS beginning template that most people are likely to end up with doing this for the first time.  (The screenshot is showing different text, AWSLambdaNew).  Make sure the dialog has the correct values, the Publish action works off what's in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error when I renamed my project and tried to Publish to AWS.
 You can fix this in your function upload screen by changing your 'Assembly Name' to match the name of your project / generated assembly.

Since, if you've chosen the save settings for future deployments option, these settings are saved to aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json, you can search for the missing file name ("AWSLambda1" in this case ) in your entire solution, see if it's present in the json file mentioned above and change it to match your assembly name.

Comment: This error also occurred for me when using the AWS SQS template project for .NET Core 3.1. It set the assembly name to be the same as the project and that throws this error on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com) to run Lambda functions. I could invoke the function but it didn't work when I tried invoking it through the API Gateway. After trying for a couple of days I solved it this way:

Handler.cs:

```
using System; 
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json;
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;

[assembly:LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace AwsDotnetCsharp { 
    public class Handler { 
        public APIGatewayProxyResponse Hello(APIGatewayProxyRequest request) { 
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponse() {
                StatusCode = 200, 
                Body = "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!", 
            }; 
        }    
    } 
}
```

serverless.yml:

```
service: csharpExample

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnetcore1.0

package:
  artifact: bin/release/netcoreapp1.0/deploy-package.zip

functions:
  hello:
    handler: CsharpHandlers::AwsDotnetCsharp.Handler::Hello
    events:
        - http:
            path: hello
            method: GET
            cors: true
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were asking for, but since I spent a lot of time on this issue I'd like to share it for anyone who runs into the same problem as I did.